# How can I stop the table from moving to a different page?

Tags: tables, floats

I have a long table in this format that starts in the middle of the first page. But when I populate the table, it moves to the second page instead of continuing from the first page. How can I do it?

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}}
%    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Requirements}} &        
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{My Qualifications}} \\ 
%    \midrule
Education & 4 years experience.\\

Modeling & Have modeled.\\

%    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: @MaartenDhondt - Not a duplicate. The current posting is about allowing a line break inside the tabular material, not about keeping the entire tabular/table material "close" to either where it's mentioned or the location where the tabular code occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the table to include a page break use `longtable` (`\usepackage{longtable}`) and then replace `tabular` with `longtable`. Also, do take care not to let the width of the `longtable` (or the `tabular`, for that matter) environment exceed the width of the textblock.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,calc,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} p{0.4\linewidth-\tabcolsep} p{0.6\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}

\toprule
\textbf{Requirements} & \textbf{My Qualifications} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Education & 4 years experience.\\
Modeling & Have modeled.\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it into an MWE and to set the width of the `longtable` equal to `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 0):

As you clearly want your table to spread over the whole line width, the best in my opinion would be to load the `\tablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X}@{}}

\toprule
\textbf{Requirements} & \textbf{My Qualifications} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Education & 4 years experience.\\
Modeling & Have modeled.\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```